# How to add a new rule after getting an attribute?

Tags: magento2, php

I'm a beginner in PHP and magento and facing a little problem.

After getting an attribute in the catalog list, I want to add a new rule. But the new rule only needs to show after the attribute is "filled".

I Tried this:

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bierstijl')- >getFrontend()->getValue($_product); echo "br";?>
```

But when I use this case it's breaking always, also when there is no `bierstijl` attribute.

So it has to only break when there is an attribute `bierstijl`

Does anyone know a solution for this case?

Kind regards

Comment: whats the error you getting?

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience I'm not getting any error. But when I do it this way I always get a linebreak after every attribute. I only want to get an line break when the attribute is showing.

Some products don't have the attribute 'bierstijl' but do get the line break, so then there is an empty rule. That's not the result that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this code :-

```
<?php $myattribute =  $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bierstijl')- >getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    if($myattribute){
        echo $myattribute; echo "<br>";
    }
 ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution also works. I only changed the "br" to "\n" this worked for me.

Comment: Your welcome @Nick, You can use "<br>" HTML tag to break the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement in PHP to check if a specific attribute exists and has a value for a product in Magento 2. Here's how you can do it:

```
<?php if ($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bierstijl') &&
          $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('bierstijl')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): ?>

    <br>

<?php endif; ?>
```